# iOS5 CoreData firing faults simultaneously at parent and child MOC causing crash

Tags: core-data, nested

Say I've got **4 MOC**(managed object context) like this:

**rootMOC**(Background saving)->**fetchMOC**(Background fetching)->**mainMOC**(UI related)

**rootMOC**->**networkMOC**(Network related)

```
'A->B' means A is a parent of B.
```

So the workflow is like this:

- Create objects in networkMOC,   [OK]
- Save to rootMOC,                [OK]
- Pass objectIDs to fetchMOC and mainMOC   [OK]
- call [moc **objectWithID**:objectID]   [OK]
- [moc **refreshObject**:object mergeChanges:**YES**] in **fetchMOC** & **mainMOC** to pull in changes [OK]
- Later I access a property of objects that cause a fault to be fired in fetchMOC and mainMOC at the same time  **[Boom, crash!]**

Things that I'm sure of:

- All MOCs are properly set up using **NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType** or **NSMainQueueConcurrencyType**.
- All MOC related API calls are **wrapped in performBlock**, even just accessing a property of a managed object(which may cause a fault fired).

Here's the code crashing in Thread 4(**fetchMOC**)

```
comparator = [^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                ArticleInfo* info1 = obj1;
                ArticleInfo* info2 = obj2;
                if (info2.timeStamp > info1.timeStamp) { //[Thread4 fetchMOC:Crash]
                    return NSOrderedAscending;
                } 
                else if (info2.timeStamp == info1.timeStamp) {
                    return NSOrderedSame;
                }
                else {
                    return NSOrderedDescending;
                }
            } copy];
```

---

And what's happening in mainMOC meanwhile:

```
[self.fetchMOC performBlock:^{
                    [self.fetchMOC refreshObject:self.currentUserFetchMOC mergeChanges:YES];
                    for (Stream* stream in self.currentUserFetchMOC.streams) {
                        [self.fetchMOC refreshObject:stream mergeChanges:YES];
                    }
                    [self.mainMOC performBlock:^{
                        LogMessage(@"MainMOC", 0, @"%@", @"Refresh steams Begin");
                        [self.mainMOC refreshObject:self.currentUserMainMOC mergeChanges:YES];
                        for (Stream* stream in self.currentUserMainMOC.streams) {
                            [self.mainMOC refreshObject:stream mergeChanges:YES];
                            if ([stream.uri isEqualToString:self.currentUserMainMOC.currentStreamURI]) {//Thread 1, here
                                self.currentStreamMainMOC = stream;
                            }
                        }
                        LogMessage(@"MainMOC", 0, @"%@", @"Refresh steams End");
                    }];
                }];
```

---

**EDIT**:

**WHY FAILED**:

After examining every line of my code I find out why.
I checked by replacing objectWithID with existingObjectWithID to make sure that the objects already existed in fetchMOC and mainMOC. The result was a big surprise that existingObjectWithID returned nil. So I think the reason is that [networkMOC save] doesn't save everything **synchronously** and I am not supposed to call objectWithID right after save returns.

**WORKAROUND**:

I just move all the object merging code to the **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification handler** right after calling [fetchMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification] and this time existingObjectWithID returns the valid object and no crashing again.

**STILL WONDERING**:

*Session 303 - What's New in Core Data on iOS* shows me that by using nested MOCs I can share unsaved changes between sibling MOCs and that's what I tried to implement (and I failed). As far as I know, there's no sample code/blog/video showing me what to do exactly after calling [sourceMOC save] where the Apple guy says just "pulling" the changes by simply accessing the properties of the managed objects. It's obviously **not working** just by accessing the properties!
While using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification works it's just simply TOO SLOW.
I created a thread in the Dev Forum and get no answer so far.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/624382#624382

Answer (score 0):

Zhao,

Maintaining consistency between MOCs can be tricky. MOCs are easy to create and destroy. The persistent store and its coordinator are designed to maintain consistency. The row cache is very fast. Hence, I would recommend that you create and destroy MOCs as you need them. I suspect that your problem will just disappear when you start using a new MOC for each background operation. (In my apps, that has indeed been the case.)

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for you answer and sorry for my comment so late. May be by using live MOCs(create as needed, released right after) the crashs  may disappear but it actually hides the problem and It's not suitable to my App's workflow. Anyway, I kinda found a workaround in the EDIT->WORKAROUND part.

Comment: Zhao, may I respectfully suggest that my solution doesn't hide the problem, it avoids it. My major point is that maintaining background MOCs helps you create the consistency problem. The row and object cache in the persistent store is the Core Data way to maintain that consistency. It works very well. Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry if my poor English sounds rude, you know I don't mean to. I learned that MOC design pattern form **Apple WWDC2011 video 303** and probably I learned it the wrong way because the video just mention the pattern with very few words like this(at 11:34) "**1.shared parent context 2.push to parent 3.pull in peer child.**" No sample code and no response in the Dev forum. So I create those MOCs: networkMOC for receiving network data and create Core Data objects **constantly**, sharing them through rootMOC -> fetchMOC -> mainMOC. fetchMOC is used here for async fetching.

Comment: And as you can see that my problem exists in the pull part not the push part of this _sharing pattern_. If I create temp MOCs I'll have to refetch all managed objects in those MOCs since my UIs are notified by KVO of those objects, that's quite a lot of work. By using permanent MOCs I can just setup KVO once and use them forever.

Comment: Jay, you're obviously committed to your path. May I suggest then that you make a very simple CD project with a very simple model that has nested MOCs as an experimental framework. That way you can see what is happening. This tactic always works for me when I'm not getting the results I expect from a complex framework. Good luck figuring this out. Andrew P.S. I apologize if I used your wrong name. It originally appeared that Zhao was your first name.

Comment: haha, you're using the right name. Jay is my English name. Yes, your suggestion is great. And I actually have create a small project to test out the nested MOC thing. Turns out not working. I've tried many ways to make the sharing pattern work but all failed except the one I mentioned in the EDIT section above. And I've been looking for a solution for a long time and everywhere. I guess I'll just wait for it and use the workaround temporarily. Maybe Apple guys will finally show some mercy and sending out a sample project. Thank you again for your patience and the advice!